# Before and After in the same trait

Tags: scala, specs2

I have next code test in scala, and i want before and after methods run before and after each tests, but i have an error

This is my test

```
import java.util.{Calendar, UUID}
import com.smartchat.helpers.BeforeAllAfterAll
import com.smartchat.models.SmartChat.{ComplaintReasonType,
ComplaintContentType}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.execute.{Result, AsResult}
import org.specs2.mutable.{After, Before}
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}


  class ComplaintModelTest extends DatabaseSpec{

  class TestingEnvironment extends ComplaintComponentImpl 
  with StorageComponentImpl

  val environment = new TestingEnvironment

  "Complaint model" should {


    "test get complaints by reason" in new BeforeAfterEach {
      ok
    }

    "test get complaints by type" in new BeforeAfterEach {
      ok
    }
  }

}

trait BeforeAfterEach extends Before with After{

  override def before = {
    println("++++++++++++++")
  }

  override def after = {
    println("--------------")
  }

}
```

this is output of the error

```
trait BeforeAfterEach inherits conflicting members:
[error]   method apply in trait Before of type [T](a: => T)(implicit evidence$3: org.specs2.execute.AsResult[T])org.specs2.execute.Result  and
[error]   method apply in trait After of type [T](a: => T)(implicit evidence$1: org.specs2.execute.AsResult[T])org.specs2.execute.Result
[error] (Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in trait BeforeAfterEach.)
[error] trait BeforeAfterEach extends Before with After{
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I dont know how to fix it.
I want methods run before and after each test example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define `before` and `after` methods in `BeforeAfterEach`, then you should inherit from `org.specs2.mutable.BeforeAfter`.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to achieve this is to use the existing `org.specs2.specification.BeforeAfterEach` trait:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with BeforeAfterEach {
  def before = println("before")
  def after = println("after")

  "test 1" >> ok
  "test 2" >> ok
}
```

Comment: This is described here in the User Guide: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.4/org.specs2.guide.Contexts.html